# Why AddMvc expects Action<MvcOptions> instead of MvcOptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm learning ASP.NET Core and I see that registering an MVC service looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.MaxModelValidationErrors = 100;
    });
}
```

My question is, why does the `AddMvc` method require options in the form of `Action<MvcOptions>`? Why can't I just create an instance of `MvcOptions` and pass it to the function?

Comment: if provides the flexibility to do any logic in the request pipeline when services get configured

Comment: Just a more functional way to describe options. It is better in terms of flexibility / supporting default options / etc. It imho looks better as well.

Comment: To elaborate on Ehsan's comment, the MVC pipeline is going to configure its own options as part of its creation and initialization. Passing in a delegate allows you to add your custom behavior on top of MVC's configuration based on your API's requirements, the alternative of this is to pass in `MvcOptions` - copy your options and then have MVC configure its own, which would be messy/unnecessary.

Comment: The reason why would have to be address by the actual developers, but if you want to go down the rabbit hole you can take a look at the source code https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/cdc66c5f98f73f0763573db4274b6763fbc6788d/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L78

Answer (score 21):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/5.0/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L44-L60) for `AddMvc`, you'll see that it *doesn't* create an instance of `MvcOptions` for you:

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddMvc(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MvcOptions> setupAction)
{
    ...

    var builder = services.AddMvc();
    builder.Services.Configure(setupAction);

    return builder;
}
```

Instead, it uses [`IServiceCollection.Configure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions.configure?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions_Configure__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_System_Action_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_BinderOptions__) to hook into the more general [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Behind the scenes, this adds an instance of [`IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.iconfigureoptions-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to the Dependency Injection container, which will end up running your delegate at some point later in time.

It's possible to add *multiple* instances of `IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>`, which will be run in order of registration. There's also [`IServiceCollection.PostConfigure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsservicecollectionextensions.postconfigure?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions_PostConfigure__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action___0__), which registers instances of [`IPostConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ipostconfigureoptions-1.postconfigure?view=aspnetcore-2.2) - these instances will run *after* all of the `IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>` instances ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#options-post-configuration)).

This all offers some flexibility. You can set up a pipeline of delegates for configuring `MvcOptions` in a set order, where each configuration step might come from other projects, etc. You could even have your own call to `services.Configure<MvcOptions>(...)` before your call to `AddMvc`, etc.

---

When adding the MVC services to DI, it's possible to use either `AddMvc` or `AddMvcCore`. Internally, `AddMvc` calls `AddMvcCore`, so we can think of `AddMvc` as some kind of extension of `AddMvcCore`.

`AddMvcCore` [adds its own configuration](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/5.0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L144-L153), rather than creating an instance of `MvcOptions` itself. It adds a set  of [`IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.iconfigureoptions-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [`IPostConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ipostconfigureoptions-1.postconfigure?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to the Dependency Injection container.

These two interfaces are used to assemble a form of pipeline, where all `IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>` run first (in the order they're added to DI) and all `IPostConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>` run second (again, in order). This allows `AddMvcCore` to provide some defaults (using `IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>`) and also provides the ability to make changes to `MvcOptions` once all other configurations have been applied (using `IPostConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>`).

When you call `AddMvc` and provide a delegate, said delegate will run *after* the `IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>` added by `AddMvcCore`, which provides the ability to override these defaults within your application.