# Adding Mvc options separately after adding Mvc services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

A question very specific to Net Core. I would like to write an extension method for for the `IServiceCollection`, which will do the configuration in the application.

The reason for that, if that currently, some of the components such as attribute and controller are located in separate libraries. So, I would like to write an extension method, which will take care of configuration for each of these libraries. **Configuration has to be independent of main application configuration.**

Here is the current code (which I don't enjoy, because of the reason above):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //..
    services.AddMvc(options => {
            // is needed for the library "filters". 
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(ExternalValidationActionFilterAttribute));
        })
        // is needed for the library "controllers"
        .AddApplicationPart(typeof(ExternalController).Assembly)
        .AddControllersAsServices();

    //..
    services.AddSingleton<ExternalControllerConfiguration>(new ExternalControllerConfiguration());
    services.AddSingleton<ExternalValidationAttributeConfiguration>(new ExternalValidationAttributeConfiguration());
}
```

The only method from the main application is the `AddMvc()`. The rest of the code is **specific to external libraries**. I would like to avoid mixing external library specific logic with main app logic. Ideally, refactored code should look like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //..
    services.AddMvc();
    services.ConfigureExternalAttributes();
    services.ConfigureExternalControllers();
    //..
}
```

and

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureExternalAttributes(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // TBD: check if Mvc services added
        //      if not - add new, with options
        //      if yes - add options to existing
        //          options.Filters.Add(typeof(ExternalValidationActionFilterAttribute));

        services.AddSingleton<ExternalValidationAttributeConfiguration>(new ExternalValidationAttributeConfiguration());
    }

    public static void ConfigureExternalControllers(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // TBD: check if Mvc services added
        //      if not - add new, with options
        //      if yes - add options to existing
        //          1. If 'part' not present already: .AddApplicationPart(typeof(ExternalController).Assembly)
        //          2. If 'AddControllersAsServices' not present already: .AddControllersAsServices();
        //             Else: skip

        services.AddSingleton<ExternalControllerConfiguration>(new ExternalControllerConfiguration());
    }
}
```

My last idea was to go to the git-hub, see the source-code and to come up with some solution. BUT. Are there any common ways of achieving this result? Maybe Microsoft had thought this though already, so I am trying to re-implement the wheel?

Any advises or code samples are very welcomed.

Comment: Have you seen the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147660/why-addmvc-expects-actionmvcoptions-instead-of-mvcoptions/54148525#54148525)? It explains how this stuff is achieved using the options pattern. In your case, you could add a delegate (using `services.Configure(...)`) within your extension methods that would allow your library code to be run after the entry application's code.

Comment: Not totally clear. AddMvc() also is from an 'external' lib. When you wan to place ConfigureExternalControllers() inside its lib, add the word 'Default' to the name. Otherwise, it's just a method for the Startup class.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I followed your advice, and finished creating extension method for the validation attribute. See update. Any suggestions for the "application part" ?

Comment: For that, you could create your own extension method for [`IMvcBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.imvcbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which gets returned from `AddMvc()`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin followed your advice. Great input! All resolved now :) (you can check the answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the application part, you can create custom extension class in separate library using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package as also suggested by Kirk Larkin.

1. Add "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" package in your separate library.

```bsh
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
```

2. Create a new class ExternalConfigurationExtensions.cs in your separate library and update class namespace as described below.

```cs
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class ExternalConfigurationExtensions
    {
        public static IMvcBuilder ConfigureExternalControllers(this IMvcBuilder builder)
        {
            if (builder == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

            builder.AddApplicationPart(typeof(ExternalController).Assembly);

            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Update your Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddMvc()
        .ConfigureExternalControllers();
```

Comment: Is there a way to obtain a previously configured `IMvcBuilder` from the `IServiceCollection` in order to call `AddApplicationPart` on it?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of community I was able to finalize the modifications. They are following:

```
public static partial class MvcBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IMvcBuilder ConfigureExternalAttributes(this IMvcBuilder builder, ExternalValidationAttributeConfiguration attributeConfiguration = null)
    {
        if (builder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

        builder.Services.Configure<MvcOptions>(o => {
            o.Filters.Add(typeof(ExternalValidationActionFilterAttribute));
        });

        // add default configuration
        if (attributeConfiguration == null)
            attributeConfiguration = new ExternalValidationAttributeConfiguration();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ExternalValidationAttributeConfiguration>(attributeConfiguration);

        return builder;
    }
}
```

and

```
    public static IMvcBuilder ConfigureExternalControllers(this IMvcBuilder builder, ExternalControllerConfiguration controllerConfiguration = null)
    {
        if (builder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

        var externalControllerAssembly = typeof(ExternalController).Assembly;
        builder.AddApplicationPart(externalControllerAssembly);

        // Next part is optional. Is used to add controller as a service.
        // see: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore
        // /Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreMvcBuilderExtensions.cs
        var feature = new ControllerFeature();
        builder.PartManager.PopulateFeature(feature);
        foreach (var controller in feature.Controllers
            .Where(w => w.Assembly == externalControllerAssembly)
            .Select(c => c.AsType()))
        {
            builder.Services.TryAddTransient(controller, controller);
        }

        // builder.Services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IControllerActivator, ServiceBasedControllerActivator>());

        // add default configuration
        if (controllerConfiguration == null)
            controllerConfiguration = new ExternalControllerConfiguration();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ExternalControllerConfiguration>(controllerConfiguration);

        return builder;
    }
```

I had to dig into the dotnet core source code to add controller as a service.. Otherwise all went smooth. Thank you all!

P.S. in case of attribute configuration - it is possible to use a different kind of extension like so:

```
public static void ConfigureExternalAttributes(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(o => {
        o.Filters.Add(typeof(ExternalValidationActionFilterAttribute));
    });

    services.AddSingleton<ExternalValidationAttributeConfiguration>(new ExternalValidationAttributeConfiguration());
}
```